# Ubuntu settings are locked down: `The key is not writable` - drag and drop issue/background picture

Tags: gsettings

I cannot drag and drop anything from the activities menu to the launcher/dock.  I also cannot set my background picture or the lock screen picture.

I tried this command in terminal and get the error below.

```
root@XXXX:/home/XXXXX# gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
```

Error Message:  `The key is not writable`

Would be greatly appreciated for any assistance to correct this issue.

Answer (score 1):

*This applies to any version of Linux Ubuntu running Gnome, including Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 22.04, etc.*

### How to unlock your locked-down Gnome Linux system settings

In case this applies to you, Gnome allows Linux system administrators (ex: using [Chef](https://www.chef.io/products/chef-infra), I hypothesize, as one possible tool) the ability to lock down certain settings. If you're an admin/root user on your computer, you can unlock locked-down settings by going to the directory at `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/` and then either moving files out of this directory, deleting them, or just commenting lines in them out. Any setting in any file in this directory is a locked-down setting.

### See:

1. Read more here about **how Linux sysadmins can lock down settings:**

   1. Both of these help articles talk about adding setting lock files to your `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/` directory:
   2. [Gnome Help: Lock down specific settings](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en)
   3. ***** [Gnome Help: Lock the screen when the user is idle](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-lockscreen.html.en)
2. **More on Chef:**

   1. Note: Chef isn't necessarily how your settings were locked down, but if your system administrators are using Chef, I bet it is how they are doing it.
   2. https://www.chef.io/
   3. https://www.chef.io/products/chef-infra
   4. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/chef/chef_overview.htm
   5. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_Chef
   6. https://github.com/chef/chef

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I figured it out finally.  Looks like my `~/.config` directory permissions got really messed up which caused me to not be able to add to my favorites, etc...

1. `sudo chown -R YOUR_USER_NAME ~/.config`
2. `sudo chmod -R 755 ~/.config`

That should fix it. It only took me two weeks to figure it out, so hopefully I was able to help someone out without spending that amount of time!