# gnome shell 42.9 wont show looking glass

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell development-tools true
The key is not writable
```

even sudo wont help

**Setup**

```
gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 42.9

uname -a
22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: can you try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176376/ubuntu-settings-are-locked-down-the-key-is-not-writable-drag-and-drop-issue? problem is similar. it might be permission related.

Comment: I commented out all the lines are rebooted computer. Issue persists. 

head -10 /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/*
==> /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/extensions <==
# Lock the list of enabled extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/disable-user-extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/development-tools

==> /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/extensions-mandatory <==
# Lock the list of mandatory extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/development-tools

Comment: Add this to your question. It is not readable in the comment.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Accept your answer as correct.

Comment: @user68186 why the downvote ?? My answer is not found in a clear fashion in askUbuntu and elsewhere.

Comment: I did not downvote your question!.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution. This fixed it.

Commented out lines as shown below

```
head -10 /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/*
==> /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/extensions <==
# Lock the list of enabled extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/disable-user-extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/development-tools

==> /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/extensions-mandatory <==
# Lock the list of mandatory extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions
#/org/gnome/shell/development-tools
```

Reloaded the db.

```
sudo dconf update
```

Run following line OR use dconf-editor

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell development-tools true
```